# Как правильно сказать "в своей" или "в моей" жизни

Tags: разговорная-речь

Как правильно говорить: "в своей жизни" или "в моей жизни"? Например, *я в своей жизни выбираю легкие пути*. Или: *в своей жизни я сама управляю обстоятельствами.*

Answer (score 2):

В ваших примерах употребление притяжательного местоимения свой не вызывает разночтений: ясно, что речь в обоих примерах идёт о вас и о вашей жизни. Поэтому вы вполне можете употребить местоимение *свой*:  *я в своей жизни выбираю легкие пути; в своей жизни я сама управляю обстоятельствами*.

2. **В связках с местоимениями 1 и 2 лица единственного и множественного числа, а также с глаголом в форме императива МОЖНО использовать оба местоимения: например, "Мой" и "Свой".**

Например: 
***Я отдал свою машину в ремонт = Я отдал мою машину в ремонт. 
Дай мне свой телефон = Дай мне твой телефон. 
Мы воспитываем своих детей = Мы воспитываем наших детей. 
Вы отлично демонстрируете свои знания = Вы отлично демонстрируете ваши знания.***

Внимание! В сложных предложениях, в случае, когда местоимение используется в качестве определения, нельзя использовать "Свой".

Например: 
Он счастлив, что своя книга нравится читателям. 
**(Неверно)**.

**Верно будет:** 
***Он счастлив, что его книга нравится читателям.***

Источник: https://www.ruspeach.com/learning/14121/
© www.ruspeach.com - Русский для иностранцев